# CFFILE Write- How to make Unique if there's a conflict?

Tags: coldfusion, xmlhttprequest, cffile

Any idea why CFFILE Write does not support making it unique but CFFile Upload does?

I'm using CFFILE Write to handle a GetHttpRequestData, and being able to support making it unique would be very helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it doesn't. You'll have to roll your own unique names by first checking if the file exists and if it does, then add on some additional character(s) and repeat check/add until you've found something unique.

Alternatively, you always prepend something that ought to be fairly unique (e.g. date-time-incremental number).

Comment: Gert G is correct. You have to roll your own. But IMO it is always a good idea to check cflib.org first. With most tasks, you will find "someone has already written a function for that ...". At the very least, one you can adapt to suit your needs. cflib.org/udf/createUniqueFileName

Answer (score 5):

try something like this

```
<cfscript>
    i = 1;
    myPath = 'D:\webroot\sap\returns\log';
    myFileName = orderNumber;
</cfscript>
<cfloop condition="fileExists('#myPath#\#myFileName#.xml')">
    <cfscript>
        myFileName = '#orderNumber#_#i#';
        i += 1;
    </cfscript>
    <cfif i GT 100><cfbreak /></cfif>
</cfloop>

<cffile action="write" file="#myPath#\#myFileName#.xml" output="#xmlString#"  />
```

Comment: Yep, that is basically the approach used by [createUniqueFileName](http://http://cflib.org/udf/createUniqueFileName). 'Gotta' love cflib.org.

Answer (score 4):

How about using CreateUUID() as filename?